# Doubt in the definition of intensity

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, intensity

So I know that radiant intensity is defined as "power transferred per unit solid angle per unit area which is perpendicular to the direction of propagation of energy". So now I have a very small (first) doubt, if we have an area that is emitting energy and we want to calculate the "rate of energy intercepted" by another area (not perpendicular to the direction of propagation), then do we take the perpendicular component of the area where we need the energy intercepted ($a_2$) or the perpendicular component of the area which is emitting energy E ($a_1$)?

[image]

I think the answer stays same, but I am asking this just for conceptual clarity.

Now, I also have another doubt. Intensity is always measured perpendicular to the energy propagation direction, and diffused emitter (emitting diffusely) is an emitter whose intensity emitted is independent of the direction (please correct me if I am wrong).
So the question is as follows :

*A small surface (area ${10}^{-3} m^2$) emits diffusively, and measurements indicate that the total intensity associated with emission in the normal direction I = 7000 $\frac{W}{{metre}^2 sr}$. The emitted radiation is intercepted by two surfaces, $a_1$ (perpendicular to energy direction), $a_2$ (vertical) where, area of each is ${10}^{-3} m^2$. What is the power intercepted by $a_1$ and $a_2$?(assume the direction of energy propagation is constant over the full area)*
[image]

Here, why have they given : *"intensity associated with emission in the normal direction"*?

Isn't radiant intensity always associated with emission in the normal direction, or do they mean that intensity for the direction normal to the surface *a* is 7000 $\frac{W}{{metre}^2 sr}$, but if that is the case, then how is it a diffused emitter? Have I misunderstood the meaning of the statement of the question / the definition of intensity or the aforementioned statement is of no use?
Also, Just to confirm, the answer for *$a_1$* is ${28}^{*}{10}^{-3} W$ and for *$a_2$* is ${7}^{*}{10}^{-3} W$?

Edit : I forgot to mention, but the distance of both detectors from the source is 0.5 ${m}^{2}$.

PS : Sorry for the long message and also the bad drawing, I do not have the picture of the original question with me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law see the wikipedia on Lambert's cosine law, which describes how most things that emit light vary with the angle from normal.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't actually have a doubt in the variation of light intensity with angle, i have a doubt in the 2 questions i have mentioned above.

Comment: It looks like there are several radiometric quantities being confused here. Intensity typically (but not always) refers to irradiance ($\text{W/m}^2$). This is different from radiant intensity ($\text{W/sr}$). Moreover, the "intensity" you are given has units of radiance ($\text{W/sr/m}^2$). Please make sure you understand the difference between these, and clarify which quantity you are talking about, preferably avoiding the term "intensity".

Comment: So sorry, I am actually a student right now, so I was not so familiar with these differences. I actually meant "Radiance" rather than intensity (in our class, we used the term "intensity" on a conventional basis"). Is it fine now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I indicated in a comment, that is not how radiant intensity is defined, nor does it have the correct units for radiant intensity (it should be $\text{W/sr}$). But you seem to be talking about radiance and not radiant intensity, so that's what I will assume.

I'm not sure I understand your definition of radiance. In particular, I don't know what it means to say "radiance is always measured perpendicular to the energy propagation direction". First, I would suggest giving [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance) a read. Radiance is power transferred per unit solid angle per unit projected source area. This means to calculate power intercepted by a detector, you need to calculate the solid angle the detector subtends as seen from the source, then calculate the projected area of the source as seen from the detector, and multiply these two by the radiance. Without a neat drawing that shows all the relevant angles and distances, this is the best verbal description I can give right now.

> Isn't radiant intensity always associated with emission in the normal direction, or do they mean that intensity for the direction normal to the surface *a* is 7000 $\frac{W}{{metre}^2 sr}$, but if that is the case, then how is it a diffused emitter?

Radiance isn't necessarily measured in the normal direction relative to the source. It can be measured in any direction, and in general it will depend *only* on this direction (radiance isn't a quantity that depends on your target or the distance from the source, for instance). An emitter could be emitting more power "sideways", away from the normal direction: then its radiance would be lower in the normal direction and higher away from the normal. If an emitter is perfectly diffuse, then it has the same radiance in any direction. Even though only the normal radiance is specified here, the radiance in any other direction is the same, but only because the emitter is diffuse.

Just to illustrate how radiance is used, I will show the calculation for $a_2$. Let $L$ be the radiance toward the target, $A_s$ the source area and $A_d$ the detector area and $r$ the distance between the source and the target (why isn't this given?). At an angle of $60^\circ$ off-normal, the projected source area as seen from the target is $A_p = A_s \cos 60^\circ$. The solid angle subtended by $a_2$ as seen from the source is $\Omega = (A_d \cos 30^\circ)/(4\pi r^2)$. The power intercepted by $a_2$ is $L\Omega A_p$.

Comment: In the second last statement ”The solid angle subtended by a1 as seen from the source is Ω=(Atcos30⁰)/(4πr²)”, did you mean a2 instead of a1?

Comment: Also, i forgot to mention it in my diagram, r = .5 metres

Comment: @HamLemon Yes, I meant $a_2$, thanks.

Comment: And, also in that same statement ”The solid angle subtended by a1 as seen from the source is Ω=(Atcos30⁰)/(4πr²)” here what is $A_t$ Did you mean $A_d$?

Comment: @HamLemon Yes, I was thinking of "target".

Comment: Oh ok, i understood what you have said (thanks for bearing with these misunderstanding of mine)

Comment: But i do have another doubt. What if they had given intensity = 7000 $\frac {W}{{m}^{2}}$, then what would the calculation be? The steradian part would have been omitted (it would appear in Intensity = $\frac {power}{4π{r}^{2}}$. Would the component of area of source also be omitted? Like would the final answer be  Ω = 
 LΩ$A_s$ rather than LΩ$A_p$?

Comment: @HamLemon "Intensity" is a vague term without context. This doesn't have the right units for radiance, so it's not radiance, and it needs to be specified what it means before you can do anything with it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, what is the had given that "intensity associated in normal direction is 7000 $\frac {W}{m^2}$ then what is the power intercepted by $a_1$ and $a_2$"?

Comment: @HamLemon I understood you fine. Like I said, intensity is a vague term. Since you have been using it to mean radiance but now it doesn't have the right units to be radiance, I don't know what $7000\text{ W/m}^2$ means. Is it exitance? Irradiance? I don't know, so I can't tell you what to do with it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, i meant irradiance, is it fine now?

Comment: @HamLemon Irradiance depends on the distance from the source. Assuming this is the irradiance $I$ at distance $r$ from the source (the same distance between the source and $a_2$) in the normal direction, the power intercepted by $a_2$ is $IA_d\cos 60^\circ \cos 30^\circ$. The first cosine is Lambert's cosine law, the second one is due to the fact that the projected area of $a_2$ as seen from the source is reduced because $a_2$ is not directly facing the source. I'll leave $a_1$ to you.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, i have cleared all my doubts now. Thank you for bearing with me